# How do I read in an editable file that contains words that I don't want stemmed using Lingua::Stem's add_exceptions($exceptions_hash_ref) in perl?

Tags: perl, stemming

I am using Perl's Lingua::Stem module ([Lingua::Stem](http://search.cpan.org/~snowhare/Lingua-Stem-0.84/lib/Lingua/Stem.pod)) and I want to have a text file or other editable file format to contain a list of words I do not want stemmed. I want to be able to add words to the file any time.

Their example shows:

```
add_exceptions($exceptions_hash_ref);
```

What is the best way to do this?

I used their method in hard coding some exceptions, but I want to do this with a file.

```
# adding default exceptions
Lingua::Stem::add_exceptions({ 'emily' => 'emily',
                            'driven' => 'driven',
                        });
```

Comment: Are you asking how to read a file into a hash ref? `$href = { map split, <$filehandle> }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your "editable" file is whitespace separated, like so:

```
emily emily
driven driven
```

Your code could be:

```
open my $fh, "<", "excep.txt" or die $!;
my $href = { map split, <$fh> };
Lingua::Stem::add_exceptions($href);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define a function to load exceptions from the given file:

```
sub load_exceptions {
  my $fname = shift;
  my %list;
  open (my $in, "<", $fname) or die("load_exceptions: $fname");
  while (<$in>) {
    chomp;
    $list{$_} = $_; 
  }
  close $in;
  return \%list;
}
```

And use it:

```
Lingua::Stem::add_exceptions(load_exceptions("notstem.txt"));
```

Example input file:

```
emily 
driven
```